Accessing XLM from an address
I'm trying to access my Stellar. I have the account address but I do not know how to move the Stellar from that address to my hard wallet; or even if I have staked it somewhere.
I cannot find it. Can anyone explain to me how to find it?
It was Feb 20,'24. I sent it from Coinspot Exchange.
I'd like to know if it was a scam or ???
please help

You can look up your account at https://stellar.expert and use the stellar account viewer to move funds at https://accountviewer.stellar.org/
